# Why is $value in this PHP foreach loop an array?

Tags: php, jquery, arrays, foreach

In my jQuery code I'm creating an object like this:

```
var fields = [
              ['title','New Title'],
              ['description', 'New Description'],
              ['stuff', ['one','two','three']]
             ];
var objectsArray=[
                  {
                   fields:fields
                  }
                 ];

var saveObject = {
                  command: 'test',
                  callback:'testResopnse',
                  objects: objectsArray
                 }
```

Which I then send via ajax to a PHP page like this:

```
saveDataAsParseObjects(saveObject)

function saveDataAsParseObjects(saveObj){
        $.ajax({
              type: "POST",
              dataType: "json",
              url: "php/parseFunctions.php",
              data: {data:saveObj},
              success: function(response) { 
                 console.log(response);
              },
              error: function(response) {
                 console.log(response);
              }
        });
};
```

In my PHP page I'm doing this:

```
$data= $_POST['data'];

if($data['command'] == 'test'){
    testStuff($data);
}
function testStuff($data){
    $objects = $data['objects'];
    foreach($objects as $object){
        $fields = $object['fields'];
        foreach($fields as $column => $value){

            echo is_array($value) ? 'Array, ' : 'not an Array, ';
        }
    }
}
```

Considering my original `fields` array on the jQuery page, I expect `testStuff()` to return:

`'not an Array, not an Array, Array,'`.

But instead it returns:

`'Array, Array, Array,'`

**Why is `$value` an array in this foreach loop when I expect it to by a string?**

`foreach($fields as $column => $value)`

Comment: because `['stuff', ['one','two','three']]`?

Comment: @Daren Yeah, I expect the 3rd iteration to be an array, but why are the first two iterations arrays?

Comment: you're trying to foreach the fields array. It has 3 elements. These 3 elements are array. Why it should be different?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to loop it one more time, since your `fields` array is an array of arrays (*take this pseudo as an example*):

```
Array(
    INDEX => Array(...),
    INDEX => Array(...),
    INDEX => Array(...),
)
```

All you need is 1 more loop:

```
$fields = $object['fields'];
foreach($fields as $column => $value){
    foreach($value as $key => $obj) {
        echo is_array($obj) ? 'Array, ' : 'not an Array, ';
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually what I needed in my case was  `echo is_array($value[1]) ? 'Array, ' : 'not an Array, ';` but your explanation of the problem was spot on, Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

You are iterating over this collection in most nested foreach:

```
var fields = [
    ['title','New Title'],
    ['description', 'New Description'],
    ['stuff', ['one','two','three']]
];
```

So every `$value` is also an array e.g. `['title','New Title']`. You should iterate over it one more time or change fields to object like this:

```
var fields = {
    title: 'New Title',
    description: 'New Description',
    stuff: ['one','two','three']
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Because each $value is element of *fields* array. And each element of that array is another array.

So

```
['title','New Title'],
```

in

```
var fields = [
    ['title','New Title'],
    ['description', 'New Description'],
    ['stuff', ['one','two','three']]
];
```

is array of *title* and *New title*.

If you debug or var_dump($value) in php you will see that the output is

```
array (size=2)
    0 => string 'title' (length=5)
    1 => string 'New Title' (length=9)

array (size=2)
    0 => string 'description' (length=11)
    1 => string 'New Description' (length=15)

array (size=2)
  0 => string 'stuff' (length=5)
  1 => 
array (size=3)
  0 => string 'one' (length=3)
  1 => string 'two' (length=3)
  2 => string 'three' (length=5)
```

Answer (score 0):

because the javascript variable "fields" is an array of array.

When you loop throught $fields, you loop throught this variable (aka objectsArray[0].fields)